# Wait for mouse click to execute the rest of the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quiz that after selecting the answer it will show result and move on to the next question after a set time.

Now how can i make it to show the result then pause and wait for mouse click before moving on?

```
self.rightAnswer = function(elm) {
  startSound('rightsound', false);
  //var bgcss = ($("#" + elm).toggleClass('correct'))
  $(elm).toggleClass('correct');            
  background.pause();
  setTimeout(function () {
    self.money($(".active").data('amt'));
    if(self.level() + 1 > 6) {
      $("#game").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $("#game-over").html('Thanks you!');
        $("#game-over").fadeIn('slow');
      });
    } else {
      $("#question-answer-block").fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $("#question-answer-block").fadeIn('slow');
        self.level(self.level() + 1);
        var bgcss = ($(elm).toggleClass('correct'))
        self.showAllAnswers();
        self.transitioning = false;
      });
    }
    self.resetAnswersView();
    startSound('background', true);
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: means instead of moving to next question `after a set time`, you would just wait till the client click mouse? If yes, just remove your Timeout function and change by a listener onMousedown https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Comment: @Jacky Thanks, so i just replace SetTimeOut with OnMousedown? I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: OnMousedown is a listener, it will listen to your mouse click event. There are plenty of examples out there, you can try, for me, normally, i will right it outside in a seperate function, not inside the `self.rightAnswer`

Comment: @Jacky thanks, i tried to cut off  `self.rightanswer` at `background.pause();` then put the rest on a button that trigger with `$("#nextquestion").onmousedown(function() {` but then the whole page doesn't run at all.

Comment: try to put on https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can help u easier